# Ruby files running from terminal but not from Sublime text

Tags: ruby, sublimetext

Ruby newbie.
How do I run ruby from Sublime Text -3 which are running fine from terminal but giving error in ST as mentioned below -

I had Ruby 1.9.x installed and Sublime Text-3 was able to run ruby files with Shift+Ctrl+B.
Then I upgraded to 2.1.2, followed steps from the article about it to install gems, update path and all. Now my ruby files are running fine when I trigger them from terminal. But when I try to run from ST-3 I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/xxx/UI_Automation/spec/basic_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/xxx/UI_Automation/spec/basic_test.rb"]
[dir: /home/techdigita/UI_Automation/spec]
[path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]
```

**Note:** The same program runs from terminal. And like I said I am so knew to Ruby I just followed steps to update GEM_PATH, GEM_HOME etc without thinking much. I had updated from 1.8 to 1.9 without any such issue. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: One more doubt - How do I run as rspec my_file.rb from ST?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I make it run from ST-3?? Was it necessary for a negative vote?

Comment: Hope it is clear now!! Or do you need more explaination???

Comment: As a non answer, don't. Use something like [`guard`](http://guardgem.org/) and it's [plugins](https://rubygems.org/search?query=guard-) to run your tasks on filesystem events in the background

Comment: @mtm: Can I use guard now??? Should I install and un-install ST again?? Or can I save the day from my current situation?

Comment: It was running before and even https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html is not helping me. Guess I will stop using ST :(

Comment: All you need is `gem install guard` then to setup a guard file to do what you want. It would run outside of ST, not a fix for your problem but a different way to go about running things

Comment: hmmm..will try that...will have to because any other ide I am using is giving me the same error. VIM is my only way now... :)